# Word not starting with di and men (prefix)

Tags: php, regex, prefix, suffix

I am having a problem creating a regex that suits the following criteria:

1. prefix : Not starting with “di” and “men”
2. Sequences of character : a-z
3. suffix : End with:
     • in, at, ah, iah,
     • sequences of vowel (a,e,i,o,u),
     • then “wi”,
     • sequences of consonants ending with i

This is the regex that I created, but it seems doesn't work. Please help me.

```
$count = preg_match_all("^(^\bdi|^\bmen]\w*(in|at|ah|iah)((a|e|i|o|u)(wi)((?!(a\e\i\o\u)i$/",$value,$match);
```

For example, the output should capture word "lain", not "dian".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
^((?!di|men)[a-z]+(in|at|ah|iah)[aeiou]*(?:wi)?[a-z]*i?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^((?!di|men)    assert that string does not start with 'di' or 'men'
[a-z]+          one or more sequence of characters a-z
(in|at|ah|iah)  ends with on these patterns
[aeiou]*        followed by optional sequence of vowels a,e,i,o,u
wi              followed by optional 'wi'
[a-z]*          optional sequence of characters a-z
i?)$            optional 'i'
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex 101

Comment: i've tried but it doesnt work... the output should be "lain", not "dian"

Comment: You never told us you are trying to capture/replace anything.  I have answered according to your requirements.  If you need to capture/replace, then update your question.

Comment: @shequin I updated my answer again, and it now matches the behavior you described.